# How do you iterate over an array of objects to create a new object?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to iterate over a message (which is an array of objects) coming in from a WebSocket connection to create a new object. This is the original array:

```
[
  {'id': 52, 'tag': 'RFS', 'price': 780},
  {'id': 14, 'tag': 'XGH', 'price': 341},
  {'id': 29, 'tag': 'LLP', 'price': 997},
]
```

I'm trying to use this array to create an object using the `tag` as the key:

```
{
  'RFS': {'id': 52, 'price': 780},
  'XGH': {'id': 14, 'price': 341},
  'LLP': {'id': 29, 'price': 997},
}
```

Let this object `= obj`. In Python I'd be able to do something like:

```py
>>> new_obj = {i['tag']: {'id': i['id'], 'price': i['price']} for i in obj}
>>> new_obj
{'RFS': {'id': 52, 'price': 780}, 'XGH': {'id': 14, 'price': 341}, 'LLP': {'id': 29, 'price': 997}}
```

How would I go about doing something like this in JS? I've tried experimenting with the `map` function but to no avail. I also attempted to use `reduce`:

```js
var result = obj.reduce(function(new_obj, i) {
  new_obj[i.tag] = {'id': i.id, 'price': i.price};
  return new_obj;
}, {});
```

EDIT: The `reduce` method above was unsuccessful for me. I'm probably missing something silly, but console tells me `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`, and it returns an `undefined` object.

Comment: And what's the *problem* with the code you've posted?

Comment: Sadly javascript doesn't have comprehensions like Python. `reduce()` is a pretty standard way to do this.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's telling me "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: @anakratis probably you're using React and you must provide a unique key to each item something like this `listItem.map(i=> return (<li key={i.index}>{i.itemName}</li>))`

Comment: @ABGR Absolutely on point. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: That's nothing to do with the code you've shown. The answer you've accepted does the same thing your existing code did, albeit with fancier syntax, and therefore doesn't solve the actual problem. Please provide a [mre] in the future, and research the error messages you receive: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Warning%3A+each+child+in+a+list+should+have+a+unique%22+%5Breactjs%5D

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well you're telling me it doesn't solve the problem but for me it did solve the problem. So I'm telling you it does, in fact, solve the problem. I'd be happy to provide an example in the future.

Comment: That's simply not true. ABGR's answer produces **exactly the same output** as the code you already have in your post (as do all of the others, for that matter). It **does not** solve the actual problem, which is apparently that in some *other* code (that you still don't actually show) you didn't set the `key` prop that [the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) helpfully remind you is needed.

Comment: I didn't change anything else except for replacing my fragment with ABGR's fragment and the error vanished.

Comment: For the reason above, that can't be true. You can prove it to yourself by replacing that one change with the code in your question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Don't get me wrong, I'm not negating what you are saying, however, I'm simply telling you exactly what I did. Like I said I'm very new to React and I'm still trying to understand why this works along with other aspects. I've also read through the documentation and though I'm sure in some way it did answer my question, perhaps I didn't understand my own problem well enough. Therefore, I figured it'd be better to ask an expert here, who is under no obligation to respond to my question, and who may point me in the right direction.

Comment: You are directly and specifically negating what I'm saying.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not negating "you didn't set the key prop that the React docs helpfully remind you is needed". I'm telling you by replacing my fragment with ABGR's fragment my site was able to render without any breaking errors.

Comment: Yes, and that's specially and directly negating what I'm saying. I don't know what's unclear about *"does the same thing"* or *"exactly the same output"*. Your problem **cannot** have been solved (only) by switching your code for the code in ABGR's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.reduce` and `de-structuring`

```js
var data = [
  {'id': 52, 'tag': 'RFS', 'price': 780},
  {'id': 14, 'tag': 'XGH', 'price': 341},
  {'id': 29, 'tag': 'LLP', 'price': 997},
];

var res= data.reduce((acc, {id, price, tag})=>{
  acc[tag] = {id, price};
  return acc
},{});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `reduce`:

```js
const input = [
  {'id': 52, 'tag': 'RFS', 'price': 780},
  {'id': 14, 'tag': 'XGH', 'price': 341},
  {'id': 29, 'tag': 'LLP', 'price': 997},
];

const output = input.reduce((acc, obj) => ({ ...acc, [obj.tag]: { id: obj.id, price: obj.price }}), {});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Hey Robin; I mentioned I tried with `reduce` and you are correct in assuming that I didn't get it to work. I was looking for help in clearing up my code or in any other method to do what I was attempting to do. Thanks again, though :)